# How to make an abstract getter in C# so you don't have to declare in every child?

Tags: c#, oop, abstract-class, getter, abstract-methods

I have an abstract class that has a implements a abstract method, that works as a placeholder for the getters of a certain value in its childs:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    public abstract int GetMyValue();
}

public class MyChildClass0 : MyAbstractClass {
    int myValue = 1;

    public override int GetMyValue {
        return myValue;
    }
}

public class MyChildClass1 : MyAbstractClass {
    int myValue = 7;

    public override int GetMyValue {
        return myValue;
    }
```

As you can see, the getter behaves the same way in every child. My question is if there is any way to make that getter a non-abstract method, so I just have to implement it once in the abstract class. And everytime I want to access myValue in any child class, I just call the GetMyValue method that it inherits from MyAbstractClass.

I don't know how to do it because I don't know how to make the getter access that field, since it is not declared in the abstract class, but in the childs.

Answer (score 1):

Properties and a default constructor are a great thing here.

This forces all derived classes to provide the value to `MyAbstractClass`.

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    protected MyAbstractClass(int myValue) 
    {
       MyValue = myValue;
    }
    public int MyValue { get; }
}
```

Comment: This is different from OPs class, as you have enabled the external instantiation control of the value of `MyValue`.

OP's code has `MyValue` tightly coupled to the class itself in an immutable manner. `MyChildClass1` will always have a `MyValue` of 7, nothing else.

This is a job for Abstract Properties.

Answer (score 0):

In your specific case you want an int tightly coupled to the implementation class, but is exposed readonly publicly, but also presumably you want Compilation Time errors, not Runtime errors, if someone forgot to set `MyValue` on the class, and the value is specified at the Class level, not the Constructor level (the thing that creates an instance of your class cannot set/modify the classes `MyValue`, its inherent to the class)

The following will work:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    public abstract int MyValue { get; }
}

public class MyChildClass0 : MyAbstractClass {
    // C#6 I believe added this handy shorthand for Getter Properties
    public override int MyValue => 1;
}

public class MyChildClass1 : MyAbstractClass {
    // This is the same as above
    public override int MyValue {
        get => 7;
    }
}
```

The compiler will pester you and demand that `MyValue` is implemented on your implementation concrete class before it will compile, which is ideal, as this enforces it to be set.

Comment: Thanks, but I may have explained wrong.

I want to have the getter declared in the abstract class so I don't have to write it in every child. In your code you write the getter everytime (in a handy shorthand but you are).

What I wanted is something like
`code

public abstract class MyAbstractClass{ \
    public abstract int MyValue{ \
        return myValue;  \
    }  \
}  \
`
But I can't access my value since it's declared separately in each child.

Comment: If you want MyValue to be different in each class without an exposed way to set it externally, then you have to have *something* in each class that sets the value.

This is the cleanest way to set the value without providing a way for external methods to mutate it. The other option would be setting the value inside the constructor, but that will net even more lines of code (~3 lines per class vs my solution which is one)

What you have written in your method there is the same as what I have above, but Getters are just syntactical sugar to simplify the process without having to write that

Answer (score -2):

Since `GetMyValue` is going to always return `myValue` why you can't just move `myValue` into the abstract class?

Something like this:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass {
    int myValue;

    public int GetMyValue() {
        return myValue;
    }

    // If you want to change myValue you could also create a setter
    public int SetMyValue(int myValue) {
        this.myValue = myValue;
    }
}

public class MyChildClass0 : MyAbstractClass {
    public MyChildClass() {
        // In constructor you can call a setter to update your value
        SetMyValue(1);
        // Or you could mark myValue as a protected field so 
        // that MyAbstractClass children had access to it. 
        // Then you could just directly assign a value to it
    }
}

public class MyChildClass1 : MyAbstractClass {
    public MyChildClass1() {
        SetMyValue(7);
    }
}
```

Comment: Manually declaring any method with "SetMyThing" is a code smell in C#, that is what Properties are for, which already have Setter and Getters you can bind.

Comment: Would that change the abstract class' value?

In your example, MyAbstractClass has a field called myValue, and its childs are only modifying their Father's field. But I want to have a separate value for every child.